# ¿Hay alguna forma de marcar días en calendarview?

Tags: android

Tengo el objetivo de marcar varios días en calendar view, y que al hacer click en uno de ellos, muestre un determinado texto mediante un toast. Este es mi código, que es muy poco, porque no tengo ni idea de si se puede hacer esto.

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
    private CalendarView miCalendario;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public InicioFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        miCalendario = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Te refieres a marcar unos dias predeterminados o que el usuario seleccione los dias?

Comment: Me gustaría que al pasarle yo una fecha, en el calendario apareciese esa fecha marcada en algún color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes en este caso podrías usar una librería como [mCalendarView](https://github.com/SpongeBobSun/mCalendarView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2420), agrega la dependencia dentro de tu `build.gradle`, recuerda que funciona desde `minSdkVersion 16`:

`dependencies {
    compile 'sun.bob:mcalendarview:1.0.0'
}`

Agrega tu vista:

```
<sun.bob.mcalendarview.MCalendarView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/calendar"/>
```

De esta forma puedes definir varios puntos:

```
    MCalendarView calendarView = (MCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    calendarView.markDate(2018, 5, 29);
    calendarView.markDate(2018, 5, 27);
    calendarView.markDate(2018, 5, 25);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y para mostrar la fecha puedes asignar un lister:

```
   calendarView.setOnDateClickListener(new OnDateClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateClick(View view, DateData date) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Today is : " + date.getDayString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece interesante. Me servirá. Gracias.

Comment: Perdona,¿sabes si hay alguna forma de cambiarle el color? Gracias

Comment: Estoy utilizando la misma librería y quería preguntarte si sabes si hay manera de modificar los formatos de las fechas, sabes no me gusta que sale 2019-4 preferiría algo como Julio-2019 pero no se si se pueda, tu sabes algo? te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: @luissanchez si tienes una nueva pregunta, debes crear tu propia publicación (siempre podrías referenciar ésta como base). Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.